# Why goroutine hangs?

Tags: go, amazon-sqs, channel, goroutine

I am trying to poll a SQS queue and get only the message(s) that meet a specific condition after unmarshalling the message body into a json event payload. I am seeing that when invoking in one test `GetMessages` that then invokes `pollQueue`, the output is something like

```
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Length of messages 1Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Length of messages 1Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Message number 1 sent
Length of messages 1Message number 1 sent
```

When the method is invoking multiple times throughout a test run it just hangs. Can you please help with the above?

```
func GetMessages[T any](ctx context.Context, awsconfig aws.Config, queueName string, maxNumberOfMessages int32,
    filter func(t T) bool) ([]T, error) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    ch := make(chan *types.Message, maxNumberOfMessages)

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        pollQueue(ctx, ch, awsconfig, queueName, maxNumberOfMessages)
        wg.Wait()
    }()
    

    var payload T
    var messages []T

    for message := range ch {
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(*message.Body), &payload)
        if err != nil {
            logging.WithError(err).Errorf("Failed to parse JSON for message %s", *message.MessageId)
        }
        if filter(payload) {
            messages = append(messages, payload)
            if len(messages) == int(maxNumberOfMessages) {
                break
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("Length of messages %d", len(messages))
    return messages, nil
}

func pollQueue(ctx context.Context, ch chan<- *types.Message, awsconfig aws.Config, queueName string, maxNumberOfMessages int32) {
    sqsClient := sqs.NewFromConfig(awsconfig)
    queueURLOut, err := sqsClient.GetQueueUrl(ctx, &sqs.GetQueueUrlInput{
        QueueName: aws.String(queueName),
    })
    if err != nil {
        _ = fmt.Errorf("could not get queue, error is : %w", err)
    }

    for {
        msgs, err := sqsClient.ReceiveMessage(ctx, &sqs.ReceiveMessageInput{
            QueueUrl:            queueURLOut.QueueUrl,
            MaxNumberOfMessages: maxNumberOfMessages,
            WaitTimeSeconds:     1,
        })
        if err != nil {
            _ = fmt.Errorf("failed to fetch messages, error is: %w", err)
        }

        for i, message := range msgs.Messages {
            ch <- &message
            fmt.Printf("Message number %d sent\n", i+1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there messages left to receive? (`sqsClient.ReceiveMessage` will return an empty slice if no messages are available within a second). As `GetMessages` only exits when you have a preset number of messages it makes sense that two goroutines, each retrieving approximately half of the messages, may mean the limit is never hit.

Comment: `wg.Wait()` should be placed outside of the goroutine :)

Comment: A further issue is that `pollQueue` loops forever. This may mean more messages are consumed that you are expecting. After `GetMessages` terminates, `pollQueue` will get some more messages, looping until the channel reaches capacity (when it will block permanently). As mentioned above your use of `var wg sync.WaitGroup` is erroneous, however as `pollQueue` never exits, `wg.Wait()` is never executed, so it's not your current problem...

Comment: No, there are no other messages to be received. The main purpose is that I want to optimize the polling time/make the whole process more robust, considering the `GetMessages` function will be invoked in parallel and it's likely it will read from the same queue. I agree that the `wg.Wait()` call should be place outside, which is something I already did. It did not work though. It's actually even worse in that case as the function hangs even in the case of just one test running, which results in function getting stuck. Consider that in all the invocations `maxNumberOfMessages` is always `1` atm.

Comment: Then main issue is that you are starting `pollQueue` every time an instance of `GetMessages` starts. Create a single channel then start some producers, that send data (from `sqsClient.ReceiveMessage`) to the channel, and consumers that receive (one consumer may be all that's needed).

Comment: `WaitTimeSeconds:     1,` I strongly suggest you set this to the maximum allowed value.  Otherwise you end up making a *lot* of calls to ReceiveMessages - 86400 * 30. Maxing out WaitTimeSeconds generally has the desired behavior.